# Looking for a reliable mapping of Forms.Screen.DeviceName to Monitor EDID info

Tags: windows, winforms, winapi, monitor, edid

I'm developing an application which will display information derived from the EDID blocks (monitor model, ID, S/N, etc.) on a dialog on the corresponding monitor.

[This code](http://wmimonitor.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/wmimonitor/DisplayInfoWMIProvider/WMIProvider/WMIProvider.cs?view=markup) works for finding the EDID information for displays.  It extracts the EDID information by enumerating the DISPLAY keys under **HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\DISPLAY\[Monitor]\[PnPID]\Device Parameters\EDID**.

***Update:** The above code is relying on "side effects" of PnP use of the registry.  I am now using the [SetupAPI](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/setupapi.setupdienumdeviceinterfaces) to enumerate monitors, which correctly handles monitors being attached/removed (unlike the code from the link above.)*

I am trying to correlate each Screen in Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens[] (\\.\DISPLAY1, \\.\DISPLAY2, etc.) with the entries returned from the above registry inspection.

*Note: In the code block below, DisplayDetails.GetMonitorDetails() has now been replaced with more robust registry enumeration code using the SetupAPI, but the data returned is the same.*

e.g.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Polling displays on {0}:", System.Environment.MachineName);
    int i = 0;
    foreach ( DisplayDetails dd in DisplayDetails.GetMonitorDetails())
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "Info: Model: {0}, MonitorID: {1}, PnPID: {2}, Serial#:{3}", dd.Model, dd.MonitorID, dd.PnPID, dd.SerialNumber );
        Console.WriteLine( "Does this correlate to Screen: {0}?", Screen.AllScreens[i++].DeviceName );
    }
}
```

### Output:

Info: Model: DELL P2411H, MonitorID: DELA06E, PnPID: 5&2e2fefea&0&UID1078018, Serial#:F8NDP0C...PU

Does this correlate to Screen: \\.\DISPLAY1?

Info: Model: DELL P2411H, MonitorID: DELA06E, PnPID: 5&2e2fefea&0&UID1078019, Serial#:F8NDP0C...AU

Does this correlate to Screen: \\.\DISPLAY2?

---

**Answer: NO**

In testing, I've found these don't reliably correlate (I have a system in which the first display enumerated is \\.\DISPLAY2).

My Question: 
***Is there a way to reliably get the EDID information for a given Forms.Screen?***  I can get the EDID block, but have found no path to correlate this up to the UI top-level Form.  Prompting the user is undesirable, as in my use case the two (or more) monitors will likely be the same model and resolution, and only differ by a few digits in the S/N.

I've looked for paths following the Forms.Screen API, Win32 EnumDisplay, other registry GUIDs (PnP and driver-related), but haven't found any promising paths.

I have also investigated the WMI Win32_DesktopMonitor API (Windows 7), however it doesn't appear to have any more information that would help me correlate it to the Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens[] entries.

I suspect if there is a way to do this, it's through the SetupAPI, however I haven't found it yet.

Comment: You are not supposed to use the registry key directly.  Proper way is through SetupDiGetClassDevices(GUID_DEVINTERFACE_MONITOR) + SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces + SetupDiOpenDevRegKey.  Some odds that this can respond to PnP events better, no idea if it does.

Comment: A believe you're suggesting that using the SetupAPI might avoid the "false positive" problem on a disconnect, and that I continue to rely on the order of enumeration matching the entries in Forms.Screen.AllScreens[]?  That's worth a try.

Comment: The good news: using the SetupAPI to enumerate the devices does remove the "false positive", and reliably returns only the currently attached displays (unlike the DisplayInfoWMIProvider code I had been using).  The bad news: I have a test configuration that fails to match the correct display (Forms.Screen.AllScreens[] doesn't match enum order).  I'm still searching for a solution.

Comment: NOTE: Bounty is now looking for answer to part a) __...solution that explicitly binds the two...__ Sorry - I can't update the bounty text (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Comment: Get the device name out of SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail().  Don't assume an order.

Comment: Avoiding assuming an order is my goal.  SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail() returns info like __DISPLAY\DELA06E\5&2E2FEFEA&0&UID1078018__ which doesn't get me any closer to mapping to a top-level Forms.Screen.AllScreens[] entry.

Comment: The DIDD doesn't resolve it, either: __DevicePath: \\?\display#dela06e#5&2e2fefea&0&uid1078018#{e6f07b5f-ee97-4a90-b076-33f57bf4eaa7}__.  The only out parms for SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail() are for the DIDD and DID (I used CM_Get_Device_ID() on the DID for the comment above, but I see notes that the CM_* API should now be avoided.)

Comment: Found the "missing link".  The DIDD path will match the results of an EnumDisplayDevices() lookup, __if you specify EDD_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_NAME__ for dwFlags!  Thanks for help, Hans (feel free to post an answer if you want the bounty)

Comment: could you please post the entire solution?

Comment: yeah, the final solution would be pretty handy, can you post it please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A method to resolve the GDI to SetupAPI is available in the [EnumDisplayDevices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumdisplaydevicesa) API.  If you pass in the **EDD_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_NAME** in for dwFlags, the monitor enumeration will return DeviceID information of the form:

```
Monitor 0 info:
DeviceName: \\.\DISPLAY1
MonitorInfo: Dell P2411H(Digital)
DeviceID: \\?\DISPLAY#DELA06E#5&2e2fefea&0&UID1078018#{e6f07b5f-ee97-4a90-b076-3
3f57bf4eaa7}
Monitor 1 info:
DeviceName: \\.\DISPLAY2
MonitorInfo: Dell P2411H(Digital)
DeviceID: \\?\DISPLAY#DELA06E#5&2e2fefea&0&UID1078019#{e6f07b5f-ee97-4a90-b076-3
3f57bf4eaa7}
```

The DeviceID fields now match the results from the **didd.DevicePath**, as retrieved in the C# fragment below:

```
    Guid MonitorGUID = new Guid(Win32.GUID_DEVINTERFACE_MONITOR);

    // We start at the "root" of the device tree and look for all
    // devices that match the interface GUID of a monitor
    IntPtr h = Win32.SetupDiGetClassDevs(ref MonitorGUID, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, (uint)(Win32.DIGCF_PRESENT | Win32.DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE));
    if (h.ToInt64() != Win32.INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        bool Success = true;
        uint i = 0;
        while (Success)
        {
            // create a Device Interface Data structure
            Win32.SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA dia = new Win32.SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA();
            dia.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(dia);

            // start the enumeration 
            Success = Win32.SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(h, IntPtr.Zero, ref MonitorGUID, i, ref dia);
            if (Success)
            {
                // build a DevInfo Data structure
                Win32.SP_DEVINFO_DATA da = new Win32.SP_DEVINFO_DATA();
                da.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(da);

                // build a Device Interface Detail Data structure
                Win32.SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA didd = new Win32.SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA();
                didd.cbSize = (uint)(4 + Marshal.SystemDefaultCharSize); // trust me :)

                // now we can get some more detailed information
                uint nRequiredSize = 0;
                uint nBytes = Win32.BUFFER_SIZE;
                if (Win32.SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(h, ref dia, ref didd, nBytes, out nRequiredSize, ref da))
                {
                    // Now we get the InstanceID
                    IntPtr ptrInstanceBuf = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)nBytes);
                    Win32.CM_Get_Device_ID(da.DevInst, ptrInstanceBuf, (int)nBytes, 0);
                    string InstanceID = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(ptrInstanceBuf);
                    Console.WriteLine("InstanceID: {0}", InstanceID );
                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptrInstanceBuf);
                   
                    Console.WriteLine("DevicePath: {0}", didd.DevicePath );
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    Win32.SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(h);
}
```

Sample Output:

```
InstanceID: DISPLAY\DELA06E\5&2E2FEFEA&0&UID1078018
DevicePath: \\?\display#dela06e#5&2e2fefea&0&uid1078018#{e6f07b5f-ee97-4a90-b076-33f57bf4eaa7}
```

The DeviceName from the original EnumDisplayDevices matches the Forms.Screen.DeviceName property.

With these two pieces of information, it is now possible to read the EDID block during the **SetupDIEnumDeviceInterface** traversal using a fragment like the below:

```
private static byte[] GetMonitorEDID(IntPtr pDevInfoSet, SP_DEVINFO_DATA deviceInfoData)
{
    IntPtr hDeviceRegistryKey = SetupDiOpenDevRegKey(pDevInfoSet, ref deviceInfoData,
        DICS_FLAG_GLOBAL, 0, DIREG_DEV, KEY_QUERY_VALUE);
    if (hDeviceRegistryKey == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        throw new Exception("Failed to open a registry key for device-specific configuration information");
    }

    IntPtr ptrBuff = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)256);
    try
    {
        RegistryValueKind lpRegKeyType = RegistryValueKind.Binary;
        int length = 256;
        uint result = RegQueryValueEx(hDeviceRegistryKey, "EDID", 0, ref lpRegKeyType, ptrBuff, ref length);
        if (result != 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Can not read registry value EDID for device " + deviceInfoData.ClassGuid);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        RegCloseKey(hDeviceRegistryKey);
    }
    byte[] edidBlock = new byte[256];
    Marshal.Copy(ptrBuff, edidBlock, 0, 256);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptrBuff);
    return edidBlock;
}
```

Which, finally, can be parsed for the VESA descriptor blocks, as shown in the [DisplayDetails.GetMonitorDetails() method in this code.](https://sourceforge.net/p/wmimonitor/code/HEAD/tree/DisplayInfoWMIProvider/WMIProvider/WMIProvider.cs)

Comment: how did you get the "MonitorInfo: Dell P2411H(Digital)" string ?

Comment: @m0sa - From the EnumDisplayDevices API the DeviceString field.  Info on how to PInvoke that can be found here: http://www.pinvoke.net/search.aspx?search=EnumDisplayDevices&namespace=[All]

Comment: Can you please submit the Win32 class?

Comment: The Win32 classes are also from pinvoke.net - links are above.

Comment: This isn't working -- maybe things have changed. But the `DeviceID` no longer matches the `DevicePath` or `InstanceID`

Answer (score 0):

I found a script that does exactly what you need. However, I don't know why the outVar.DeviceID variable is empty, could someone tell me. Without the DeviceID information, it is then not possible to map the EDID information.

Thank you, Mathew

```
using System; 
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; 
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Resolution 
{ 
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)] 
    public struct DEVMODE1 
    { 
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)] 
        public string dmDeviceName; 
        public short dmSpecVersion; 
        public short dmDriverVersion; 
        public short dmSize; 
        public short dmDriverExtra; 
        public int dmFields; 
        public short dmOrientation; 
        public short dmPaperSize; 
        public short dmPaperLength; 
        public short dmPaperWidth; 
        public short dmScale; 
        public short dmCopies; 
        public short dmDefaultSource; 
        public short dmPrintQuality; 
        public short dmColor; 
        public short dmDuplex; 
        public short dmYResolution; 
        public short dmTTOption; 
        public short dmCollate; 
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)] 
        public string dmFormName; 
        public short dmLogPixels; 
        public short dmBitsPerPel; 
        public int dmPelsWidth; 
        public int dmPelsHeight; 
        public int dmDisplayFlags; 
        public int dmDisplayFrequency; 
        public int dmICMMethod; 
        public int dmICMIntent; 
        public int dmMediaType; 
        public int dmDitherType; 
        public int dmReserved1; 
        public int dmReserved2; 
        public int dmPanningWidth; 
        public int dmPanningHeight; 
    }; 
    
    [Flags()]
    public enum DisplayDeviceStateFlags : int
    {
        /// <summary>The device is part of the desktop.</summary>
        AttachedToDesktop = 0x1,
        MultiDriver = 0x2,
        /// <summary>The device is part of the desktop.</summary>
        PrimaryDevice = 0x4,
        /// <summary>Represents a pseudo device used to mirror application drawing for remoting or other purposes.</summary>
        MirroringDriver = 0x8,
        /// <summary>The device is VGA compatible.</summary>
        VGACompatible = 0x10,
        /// <summary>The device is removable; it cannot be the primary display.</summary>
        Removable = 0x20,
        /// <summary>The device has more display modes than its output devices support.</summary>
        ModesPruned = 0x8000000,
        Remote = 0x4000000,
        Disconnect = 0x2000000
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
    public struct DISPLAY_DEVICE 
    {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
            public int cb;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=32)]
            public string DeviceName;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=128)]
            public string DeviceString;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
            public DisplayDeviceStateFlags StateFlags;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=128)]
            public string DeviceID;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=128)]
            public string DeviceKey;
    }
    class User_32 
    { 
        [DllImport("user32.dll")] 
        public static extern int EnumDisplaySettings(string deviceName, int modeNum, ref DEVMODE1 devMode); 
        [DllImport("user32.dll")] 
        public static extern int ChangeDisplaySettings(ref DEVMODE1 devMode, int flags); 
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool EnumDisplayDevices(string lpDevice, uint iDevNum, ref DISPLAY_DEVICE lpDisplayDevice, uint dwFlags);
        public const int ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS = -1; 
        public const int CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY = 0x01; 
        public const int CDS_TEST = 0x02; 
        public const int DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL = 0; 
        public const int DISP_CHANGE_RESTART = 1; 
        public const int DISP_CHANGE_FAILED = -1; 
    } 
    public class Displays
    {
        public static IList<string> GetDisplayNames()
        {
            var returnVals = new List<string>();
            for(var x=0U; x<1024; ++x)
            {
                DISPLAY_DEVICE outVar = new DISPLAY_DEVICE();
                outVar.cb = (short)Marshal.SizeOf(outVar);

                if(User_32.EnumDisplayDevices(null, x, ref outVar, 1U))
                {
                    Regex regex = new Regex(DisplayDeviceStateFlags.AttachedToDesktop.ToString());
                    Match match = regex.Match(outVar.StateFlags.ToString());

                    if (match.Success)
                    {
                        returnVals.Add(outVar.DeviceName + ":" + outVar.DeviceID);
                    }
                }
            }
            return returnVals;
        }
        
        public static string GetCurrentResolution(string deviceName)
        {
            string returnValue = null;
            DEVMODE1 dm = GetDevMode1();
            if (0 != User_32.EnumDisplaySettings(deviceName, User_32.ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, ref dm))
            {
                returnValue = dm.dmPelsWidth + "x" + dm.dmPelsHeight;
            }
            return returnValue;
        }
        
        public static IList<string> GetResolutions()
        {
            var displays = GetDisplayNames();
            var returnValue = new List<string>();
            foreach(var display in displays)
            {
                string[] ds = display.Split(':');
                returnValue.Add(ds[0] + ";" + GetCurrentResolution(ds[0]) + ";" + ds[1]);
            }
            return returnValue;
        }
        
        private static DEVMODE1 GetDevMode1() 
        { 
            DEVMODE1 dm = new DEVMODE1(); 
            dm.dmDeviceName = new String(new char[32]); 
            dm.dmFormName = new String(new char[32]); 
            dm.dmSize = (short)Marshal.SizeOf(dm); 
            return dm; 
        }

    }
}
```