# Link info from EnumDisplayDevices with info from SetupDiOpenDevRegKey (EDID)

Tags: windows, display, setupapi, edid

Windows 7, multi-monitors configurations.

Cross compiled on linux (opensuse 13.1) with gcc-mingw-5.1.0 (which may actually be the cause of me not getting the expected values).

I get a list of all display devices with **EnumDisplayDevices**:
Code:

```
int DispNum = 0;
DISPLAY_DEVICE DisplayDevice;
DEVMODE defaultMode;

// initialize DisplayDevice
ZeroMemory(&DisplayDevice, sizeof(DisplayDevice));
DisplayDevice.cb = sizeof(DisplayDevice);

while (EnumDisplayDevices(NULL, DispNum, &DisplayDevice, EDD_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_NAME))
{
    ZeroMemory(&defaultMode, sizeof(DEVMODE));
    defaultMode.dmSize = sizeof(DEVMODE);

    if ((DisplayDevice.StateFlags & DISPLAY_DEVICE_ACTIVE) && (DisplayDevice.StateFlags & DISPLAY_DEVICE_ATTACHED_TO_DESKTOP) && !(DisplayDevice.StateFlags & DISPLAY_DEVICE_MIRRORING_DRIVER)) {
        printf("%d -> %s\n\tstr=%s\n\tid=%s\n\tkey=%s\n\tprimary=%s\n", DispNum,DisplayDevice.DeviceName, DisplayDevice.DeviceString,
            DisplayDevice.DeviceID, DisplayDevice.DeviceKey,
            (DisplayDevice.StateFlags & DISPLAY_DEVICE_PRIMARY_DEVICE) ? "y":"n");

        if (!EnumDisplaySettings((LPSTR)DisplayDevice.DeviceName, ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, &defaultMode) ) {
            puts("EnumDisplaySettings failed\n");
        } else {
            printf("    -> bpp=%d w=%d h=%d fps=%d\n",
                (int)defaultMode.dmBitsPerPel, (int)defaultMode.dmPelsWidth,
                (int)defaultMode.dmPelsHeight, (int)defaultMode.dmDisplayFrequency);
        }
    }

    // Reinit DisplayDevice just to be extra clean
    ZeroMemory(&DisplayDevice, sizeof(DisplayDevice));
    DisplayDevice.cb = sizeof(DisplayDevice);
    DispNum++;
}
```

Output (emphasis mine):

> 0 -> \.\DISPLAY1 
>   str=Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600
>    **id=PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0416&SUBSYS_397817AA&REV_06** 
>       key=\Registry\Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Video{BBECD187-6CE4-47FD-915A-A4952B2AC000}\0000 
>       primary=y 
>       -> bpp=32 w=1920 h=1080 fps=60 
>   
>   1 -> \.\DISPLAY2 
>       str=Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600
>       **id=PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0416&SUBSYS_397817AA&REV_06**
>       key=\Registry\Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Video{BBECD187-6CE4-47FD-915A-A4952B2AC000}\0001
>       primary=n
>       -> bpp=32 w=1920 h=1080 fps=60

Now, with [this article](https://ofekshilon.com/2011/11/13/reading-monitor-physical-dimensions-or-getting-the-edid-the-right-way/) I can get the EDID of each monitor:

```
const GUID GUID_CLASS_MONITOR = {0x4d36e96e, 0xe325, 0x11ce, 0xbf, 0xc1, 0x08, 0x00, 0x2b, 0xe1, 0x03, 0x18};

HDEVINFO devInfo = NULL;
SP_DEVINFO_DATA devInfoData;
ULONG i = 0;

devInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevsEx(
    &GUID_CLASS_MONITOR, //class GUID
    NULL,NULL,
    DIGCF_PRESENT,
    NULL,NULL,NULL);

if (NULL == devInfo)
return -1;

for (i=0;ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS != GetLastError();i++) {
    memset(&devInfoData,0,sizeof(devInfoData));
    devInfoData.cbSize = sizeof(devInfoData);

    if (SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(devInfo,i,&devInfoData))
    {
        // look for EDID with SetupDiOpenDevRegKey + RegEnumValue...
    }
}
```

Output (part of it):

> ... 
>   Found value EDID for 'PnP-Monitor (Standard)'
>   Key path is '\REGISTRY\MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Enum\DISPLAY\LGD044F\4&1BDB7018&0&UID68092928\Device Parameters'
>   
>   00 ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 26 07 01 00 e7 03 00 00 
>   00 1a 01 03 80 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
>   ....

My problem is now, how do I link both informations? How do I attribute an EDID to a Display?

Expected:

\.\DISPLAY1 -> EDID1

\.\DISPLAY2 -> EDID2

Notes

1. Display #1 is an LG monitor, Display #2 is a Dell (setup as such and this can be verified when I change the resolution of Display#2), but the EDID for the Dell monitor appears first and then comes the EDID of the LG.
   Therefore I cannot use the order of appearance in both enumerations, they are not directly linked (otherwise no question to ask).
2. I also cannot rely on the resolution information or sync rate, since it may be the same for all monitors
3. I am aware of [this question and its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577736/how-to-obtain-the-correct-physical-size-of-the-monitor) but the accepted answer does not help me since it expects **DISPLAY_DEVICE.DeviceID** to be in the reg key *\HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Enum\DISPLAY* and what I get from **EnumDisplayDevices** is in *\HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Enum\PCI* (see the "id" lines in the output).
4. I tried to use the flag EDD_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_NAME as  [advised in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10237937/looking-for-a-reliable-mapping-of-forms-screen-devicename-to-monitor-edid-info) but I do not get the deviceID as shown in the accepted answer.
5. [how to get the key path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937044/determine-path-to-registry-key-from-hkey-handle-in-c)

I have checked the [list of SetupAPI functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549791(v=vs.85).aspx) but could not find how to connect display information and the result of SetupDiOpenDevRegKey.

What did I miss? Which flag did I set wrong? Can somehow I use the Key path returned by SetupDiOpenDevRegKey?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `EnumDisplayDevices` function twice for each display, like this:
[Getting the monitor's name with EnumDisplayDevices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299619/getting-the-monitors-name-with-enumdisplaydevices)

First call with `lpDevice=NULL` and second call with `lpDevice=DisplayDevice.DeviceName`

After that you received expected value in DISPLAY_DEVICE.DeviceID. For my case it has next value `"MONITOR\DVAF001\{4d36e96e-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10"`