# How to change font size for a monitor in Windows?

Tags: c#, windows

I am frequently playing games and though I have a good graphics card, it's not capable of running *all* games in 4K on my 4K monitor. Since I run all my games in borderless windowed mode, I first have to reduce the monitor resolution down to 1080p before starting the game, and I'm trying to automate this.

I have already created a program that is capable of doing this, but I need to hardcode in a few big strings that are some kind of identifier. The way the program operates is that it first:

1. Modifies the registry key `HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\PerMonitorSettings\<big id here>` and set a key beneath it to lock in the font size
2. Uses `ChangeDisplaySettingsEx` to make the *resolution* and *positioning* change to the monitor, this has the extra benefit of refreshing the monitor setting from the registry, and reacting to my registry change in point 1

Now, I have two questions but I'll concentrate on one of them here, and that question is this:

Given the device name (id?) `\\.\DISPLAY1`, is there a way to set the font size of that monitor *without* monkeying around in that registry key? I can't find a corresponding setting in the DEVMODE or DISPLAY_DEVICE structs that I am already using, and when trying to search for it using Google I can only find ways to make my own software DPI aware, which is not what I want.

I tried using `EnumDisplayDevices`, and it gives me some device id's and another registry key but I can't find anything in that structure that would let me even read the current font size.

I basically like a programmatical way to change my monitor between 4K @ 200% size and 1080p @ 100% size.

Comment: My other question, that will be posted if this one doesn't turn up anything, is how I can get from `\\\\.\\DISPLAY1` to the registry ID which looks like this: `ACI28A7160556_05_07E2_B0^F25449DC7608FE090234D904F136BDB2` without hardcoding it, I haven't found a way to discover this long ID from C#.

Comment: not related to your question, but I am curious: why don't you just use fullscreen?

Comment: you might try and look into autohotkey. It might be able to do this.

Comment: You might have a look at the other `EnumDisplay*` functions in user32.dll. There's also this answer which might give you some pointers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10303610/70345 (the comments on the question itself may also prove useful).

Comment: @bolov Because I love to be able to simply move the mouse cursor over to one of the other monitors I have to control webpages and discord etc. without having to alt-tab out of the game.