# Count monitors from a service with C++

Tags: c++, winapi, multiple-monitors

I'm trying to count the number of monitors (i.e. screens) attached to the console from a service application. I do the following:

```
int CountMonitors()
{
    int nCnt = 0;

    if(!EnumDisplayMonitors(NULL, NULL, _countMonitorEnumProc, (LPARAM)&nCnt))
    {
        //Error
        nCnt = -1;
    }

    return nCnt;
}

BOOL _countMonitorEnumProc(HMONITOR hMonitor, HDC hdcMonitor, LPRECT lprcMonitor, LPARAM dwData)
{
    int* pCnt = (int*)dwData;
    (*pCnt)++;

    return TRUE;
}
```

but the count is always 1 (when I'm testing it on a dual-monitor Windows 7.) I then do this (which is not exactly what I need due to [its limitation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724385%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#SM_CMONITORS)):

```
int nCnt = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CMONITORS);
```

and the result is also 1.

So how do you count monitors from a service?

Comment: You should check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767036/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-displays-in-windows

Comment: @user1906108: I'm sorry, but that's exactly what I did. How does it answer my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, why is the console special to a service, vs number of displays attached on a remote session?  Then, what about display mirroring / extended desktop / eyefinity?

Now, learn about [Window Stations and Desktops](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687098.aspx).  Then learn about shatter attacks.

Finally, if what you're really after is hardware enumeration, there are APIs for that.  `SetupDiGetClassDevs` on the display monitor setup class will tell you how many physical screens the video card(s) expose.

Comment: Shatter attacks? They fixed it since Vista by introducing session separation. And my software totally incorporates it. I also understand why GUI resources are separated between desktops and window stations. In my case though, local monitor(s) is a global resource, so I'm not sure why such info cannot be available from a service. Knowing the number of monitors I can optimize the service code to be more efficient.

Comment: @user843732: Yes, session separation prevents shatter attacks, as long as you leave it in place.  But it's also preventing your `EnumMonitors` call from working.  So when you tear down the wall of separation, you'd better understand shatter attacks and not leave yourself vulnerable.

Comment: OK, that is the answer then. I thought that session separation would be the issue. What is not clear to me, is why `EnumDisplayMonitors` doesn't simply fail instead of returning an incorrect answer ...

Comment: @user843732: Because it is returning the right answer for the (virtual) session the service is associated with.  It's session separation, not lack of a session.  So much stuff would fail if a service wasn't associated with some window station, since posting window messages is the heart of much of IPC (DCOM, for instance, uses window messages extensively).

Comment: I totally disagree with you on your last statement. Giving "illusion of success" for software written prior to introduction of session isolation is much worse than simply returning an error.